# What is wrong with this where clause of zend query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

Hi I am mad on not understanding the error in this where clause of zend query. My query is

```
$select->where("id=".$get['value']." OR description like '%".$get['value']."%'");
```

`$get['value']` is the query that I want to search. But result is `500 internal server error` and it always says the value of `get['value']` is unkown column. For example if I have searched `testing` for `description` column it always says that `testing` in unknown columns... why is this happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this docs [zend_db_select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.where) you may wrong in your syntax.

```
$table->select()
         ->where('id = ?', $get['value'])
         ->orWhere('description like ?', '%' . $get['value'] . '%');
```

Edited!

Comment: This looks like the right way, +1. The reason why the query is breaking is probably because `$get["value"]` contains a string, which gets interpreted as a column because of the missing quotes.

Comment: it is only searching my description columns starts with the `get['value'] word. If description columns is having a word at middle or at end then it is not wrokin

Comment: The query in original post is SQL injecion vulnerable :( This is the right way !