# Zend Framework mysql query return server 500 error

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I use Zend Framework. Code

```
$this->_db->query("INSERT INTO blog SET ....")
```

returns 500 error. But if I replace it to

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog SET ....")
```

all ok. What can be wrong?

Comment: Nothing, but it is shared hosting, so may be not all of errors displayed. I should add that on localhost everything is fine!

Comment: even shared hosting should produce something. Nothing even in the apache logs?

Comment: Nothing. If there were some info i didn't asked question here. The most interesting is that simply mysql_query is working!

Comment: Check whether the SQL you run is absolutely correct in the Zend call. Send some static SQL : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620249/what-is-wrong-with-this-where-clause-of-zend-query

Comment: Other queries and functions runs normally, even in same action file. If this could be important - in query that produce 500 I try to insert text info about 3000 charachters.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Have you tried using a save call? : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.rowset.html

Comment: Is the database credentials set up correctly in Zend?

Comment: As far as i know save() affected only on rows, but i need INSERT, not SELECT, i do not need to fetch result, i only want to insert data into table.

Comment: Database setup correctly, all other queries - ok.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `$this->_db` is what you expect it to be?

If you're using the default ErrorController, setting

`resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1`

in your /application/config/application.ini should give you a backtrace of the error.

Also, if it really is just the query generating an exception you can wrap it in a try/catch and see the exception.

```
    try {
        $this->_db->query("INSERT INTO blog SET ....");
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your SQL syntax is wrong. Correct syntax:

```
INSERT INTO  table (fields) VALUES (values)
```

EDIT: Oh sorry just read that your mysql_query() is working with the same SQL. As someone else recommended I'd recommend checking the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly your `$this->_db` is not an instance of Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract :) Even more it may be NULL ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a select statement in Zend. Simply adding a try..catch block around the $this->fetchRow($select) line solved the issue. Curiously, there were no exceptions caught..!!